# Linking target and source values

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through a list (see below) in Excel, which contains source and target ID values. When graphically representing the list below one gets a tree-like structure, in which each spot is connected to another spot. There is a division-event after which out of one spot two target spots emerge. I would like to find a way how to collect connected source and target IDs from that list.

Does anybody have any idea how to approach this problem or could give me any hints on what possible solutions there are?

```
SPOT_SOURCE_ID  SPOT_TARGET_ID
127466  127460
127460  127450
127450  127474
127450  127442
127474  127481
127442  127432
127481  127487
127432  127426
127426  127420
127487  127498
127420  127410
127498  127510
127510  127516
127410  127402
127516  127530
127530  127542
127402  127390
127542  127554
127390  127383
127554  127560
```

Comment: Lacks a proper example, specifications unclear.

Comment: Your data in text form was **far** more useful than that image! Please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: A directed graph of your data looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqaPP.png), but it's still not clear what you want your code to do.

Comment: I would like to add all values in one column, in which all ID values corresponding to one of the three tracks in this example are listed according to the order of appearance. So the first three values in the column would be listed below each other, then all values of the left track should be listed beneath each other, followed by the third track.

Comment: @PM2Ring: I would greatly appreciate it if you could tell me how you were able to generate such a directed graph from the data I provided.

Comment: I wrote a small Python script to transform your data into a [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Home.php) [DOT](http://www.graphviz.org/content/dot-language) file, then used the `dot` command-line utility to generate a PNG from it.

Comment: I have tried using for-loops to connect the source and target IDs together but nothing so far has worked. Could you elaborate what the content of your python script was?

Comment: Your Spot data is nicely ordered. Will that always be the case?

Comment: Normally that is always the case

Comment: I decided to write code that can handle data that isn't nicely ordered, although it will be a little more efficient when given ordered data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list of pairs can be considered to be the edges of a directed rooted [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29). The standard way to find all the paths is to perform a [pre-order depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Pre-order_2). We can adapt this to return the tracks that you desire. The code below contains a recursive generator `tree_paths` that generates the full paths as well as a recursive generator `tree_tracks` that generates the tracks. `tree_tracks` returns an integer `depth` along with each track list, `depth` is used to print the tracks in a structured fashion.

```
data = '''\
127466  127460
127460  127450
127450  127474
127450  127442
127474  127481
127442  127432
127481  127487
127432  127426
127426  127420
127487  127498
127420  127410
127498  127510
127510  127516
127410  127402
127516  127530
127530  127542
127402  127390
127542  127554
127390  127383
127554  127560
'''.splitlines()

# Convert multiline `data` string to a list of (parent, child) tuples 
edges = [tuple(int(u) for u in row.split()) for row in data]

# Each node in a tree can only have one parent. `v` is the parent of `k`
parents = {k: v for v, k in edges}

# Each value in `children` is a list containing the children of the key
children = {}
for u, v in edges:
    children.setdefault(u, []).append(v)

# Recursively generate every path in the tree starting at `node` 
# by performing a depth-first search
def tree_paths(node, head):
    newhead = head + [node]
    if node not in children:
        yield newhead
        return
    descendants = children[node]
    for n in descendants:
        yield from tree_paths(n, newhead)

# Recursively generate every track in the tree starting at `node` 
# by performing a depth-first search
def tree_tracks(node, head, depth=0):
    newhead = head + [node]
    if node not in children:
        yield newhead, depth
        return
    descendants = children[node]
    if len(descendants) > 1:
        yield newhead, depth 
        newhead = []
        depth += 1
    for n in descendants:
        yield from tree_tracks(n, newhead, depth)

# Find the root node.
# Start at any node. If the edges are sorted, `edges[0][0]` will be the root.
k = edges[0][0]
# Loop until we find a node without a parent. 
# That node must be the root of the tree 
while k in parents:
    k = parents[k]
root = k

print('Paths')
for seq in tree_paths(root, []):
    print(seq)

print('\nTracks')
for seq, depth in tree_tracks(root, []):
    print('{}{}'.format(' ' * 4 * depth, seq))
```

**output**

```
Paths
[127466, 127460, 127450, 127474, 127481, 127487, 127498, 127510, 127516, 127530, 127542, 127554, 127560]
[127466, 127460, 127450, 127442, 127432, 127426, 127420, 127410, 127402, 127390, 127383]

Tracks
[127466, 127460, 127450]
    [127474, 127481, 127487, 127498, 127510, 127516, 127530, 127542, 127554, 127560]
    [127442, 127432, 127426, 127420, 127410, 127402, 127390, 127383]
```

If you already know the root node, you can obviously omit the construction of the `parents` dict and the loop that searches for the root node.

If you don't need the indented output of the tracks you can use a simpler version of `tree_tracks` that doesn't use or yield `depth`.

```
def tree_tracks(node, head):
    newhead = head + [node]
    if node not in children:
        yield newhead
        return
    descendants = children[node]
    if len(descendants) > 1:
        yield newhead 
        newhead = []
    for n in descendants:
        yield from tree_tracks(n, newhead)
```

---

This code can handle more complex trees. Here's an example run that has some extra branches added to your tree data.

```
data = '''\
127466  127460
127460  127450
127450  127474
127450  127442
127474  127481
127442  127432
127481  127487
127432  127426
127426  127420
127487  127498
127420  127410
127498  127510
127510  127516
127410  127402
127516  127530
127530  127542
127402  127390
127542  127554
127390  127383
127554  127560
127510 1
1 2
2 3
3 4
127516 11
11 12
12 13
'''.splitlines()
```

**output**

```
Paths
[127466, 127460, 127450, 127474, 127481, 127487, 127498, 127510, 127516, 127530, 127542, 127554, 127560]
[127466, 127460, 127450, 127474, 127481, 127487, 127498, 127510, 127516, 11, 12, 13]
[127466, 127460, 127450, 127474, 127481, 127487, 127498, 127510, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[127466, 127460, 127450, 127442, 127432, 127426, 127420, 127410, 127402, 127390, 127383]

Tracks
[127466, 127460, 127450]
    [127474, 127481, 127487, 127498, 127510]
        [127516]
            [127530, 127542, 127554, 127560]
            [11, 12, 13]
        [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

FWIW, here is the [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/Home.php) DOT file that I used to produce the tree diagram below of your data.

```
strict digraph test{
    127466 -> 127460;
    127460 -> 127450;
    127450 -> 127474;
    127450 -> 127442;
    127474 -> 127481;
    127442 -> 127432;
    127481 -> 127487;
    127432 -> 127426;
    127426 -> 127420;
    127487 -> 127498;
    127420 -> 127410;
    127498 -> 127510;
    127510 -> 127516;
    127410 -> 127402;
    127516 -> 127530;
    127530 -> 127542;
    127402 -> 127390;
    127542 -> 127554;
    127390 -> 127383;
    127554 -> 127560;
}
```

[image: tree diagram of OP's data]